# Another question about how to make Coq accept a Fixpoint definition

Tags: coq

I have trees :

```
Inductive tree : Set :=
  | Node : list tree -> tree.
```

and a collection of Definitions I'd like to use, all with a structure of the form :

```
Fixpoint getThemAll_aux (trees: list tree) (maxIter:nat): list tree :=
 
  match maxIter with
   | O => nil
   | S n => 
       match trees with
             | nil => nil
             | xx::rest =>  let newCandidates := generateCandidates xx in
                                  let newRest := addAllIfDifferent tree eq_tree newCandidates rest in 
                                     addAllIfDifferent tree eq_tree newCandidates (getThemAll_aux newRest n)
       end
    end.
```

```
Definition getThemAll (seed:tree) : list tree :=
    getThemAll_aux (seed::nil) 999.
```

Because of maxIter , this function is accepted whatever we have for generateCandidates of type tree -> list tree, eq_tree and addAllIfDifferent.

Now suppose that I have a proof that generateCandidates produces lists of trees with the same number of Nodes as the argument, and that eq_tree and addAllIfDifferent have the expected semantics.

Is that case, the function always terminates.

Is there then a way to get rid of the maxIter parameter, in the definition of the Fixpoint ?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your definition is this 999.
If you are sure your function terminates, maybe you are capable
to write a function f that bounds the number of iterations you need.
so you can define

```
 Definition getThemAll (seed:tree) : list tree :=
    getThemAll_aux (seed::nil) (f seed).
```

and prove the theorem

```
forall trees,
getThemAll trees = 
       match trees with
             | nil => nil
             | xx::rest =>  let newCandidates := generateCandidates xx in
                                  let newRest := addAllIfDifferent tree eq_tree newCandidates rest in 
                                     addAllIfDifferent tree eq_tree newCandidates (getThemAll newRest)
       end.
```

Comment: In the statement of the theorem  you give, 'trees' is a tree, not a list of trees. You can't match trees that way.

Comment: Yes my bad,
`Definition getThemAll  trees := getThemAll_aux trees (f trees)`

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how you state the theorem without having it rejected as well with the same ill-formed definition you face in the definition of the fixpoint in the first place. Can you share the theorem ?

Comment: If you define 
`Definition getThemAll  trees := getThemAll_aux trees (f trees)`
for some  well-chosen `f`. The theorem is then :
`forall trees, getThemAll trees =  match trees with | nil => nil | xx::rest =>  let newCandidates := generateCandidates xx in let newRest := addAllIfDifferent tree eq_tree newCandidates rest in addAllIfDifferent tree eq_tree newCandidates (getThemAll newRest) end.`